# Protractor parallel running leads tests to fail

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm using protractor for automation testing, at this time all tests work properly.
But if I set test running parallel

add to config file:

```
shardTestFiles: true,
maxInstances: 4,
```

tests will start randomly fail throwing 'no element found' and/or 'failed expectation' exceptions.

Could someone suggest what can be cause of this problem or how to fix it?

Could be a cause that test fails at the moment when start running new browser instance and Protractor focusing on it? 
(At this moment i have about 20 spec files and each spec file running starts new browser instance)

environment:

```
Windows 7 x64
Protractor v2.1.0
Browser Chrome v46
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. When I run tests locally with 2 Chrome instances, they pass just fine, but with 4 I'm starting to get errors. On Travis CI even with 2 instances I'm getting random errors. I suppose these errors are somehow related to lower performance when running many Chrome instances.

Comment: see answer, here I've shared my solution of this problem

Comment: @szimek Did this solve your problem or did you fix it another way? I would rather not create wrappers and rewrite a lot of tests

Comment: @Will Unfortunately not, we just made sure that they run "fast enough" for us using single Chrome instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve my issue I've created a wrapper of elementFinder and ElementArrayFinder objects with overridden methods and some additional waiting for visibility and/or for presence.

Example for elementFinder.getText() and elementFinder.click()

```
function ElementFinderWrapper() {
    var conditions = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    /**
    * Returns a wrapper for ElementFinder element.
    * @param {webdriver.Locator} locator
    */
    this.get = function(locator){
        return new Control(element(locator));
    };

    /**
    * Creates a wrapper for ElementFinder element.
    * @param {ElementFinder} element_finder
    * @constructor
    */
    function Control(element_finder) {

        /**
        * Returns the visible innerText of this element.
        * @returns {!webdriver.promise.Promise.<string>}
        */
        this.getText = function () {
            return browser.wait(conditions.presenceOf(element_finder), 3000);
               .then(function () {
                   return browser.wait(conditions.visibilityOf(element_finder), 3000);
               })
               .then(function () {
                   return element_finder.getText();
               });
        };

        /**
        * Clicks on visible element.
        * @returns {!webdriver.promise.Promise.<void>}
        */
        this.click = function () {
            return browser.wait(conditions.presenceOf(element_finder), 3000);
               .then(function () {
                   return browser.wait(conditions.visibilityOf(element_finder), 3000);
               })
               .then(function () {
                   return element_finder.click();
               });
        };
    };
};
```

then use something like:

```
contol = ElementFinderWrapper.get(by.xpath('some path'));
control.getText();
control.click();
```

Comment: Do you know if there has been an update to this in the last year?

Comment: @Will, I don't.
It looks like this issue is still reproducible.